# Максимальный элемент из минимальных элементов строк массива

Tags: массивы, java

Нужно найти максимальный элемент из минимальных элементов строк массива и вывести на экран.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[][] = { { 23, 6, 3 },
                  { 2, 3, 4 }, 
                  { 1, 8, 2 } };
    int min = 0;
    int maxmin;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
            if (a[i][j] < a[i][min]) {
                min = j;
            }
        maxmin = a[i][min];
        if (maxmin < a[i][min]) {
            maxmin = a[i][min];
        }

        System.out.println(maxmin);
    }
}
```

Подскажите как вывести только один максимальный.

Comment: Эээ...

    maxmin = a[i][min];
    if (maxmin < a[i][min]) {

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте разделил задачу на части:

1. для каждой строки найти минимальный элемент;
2. среди найденных в предыдущем пункте элементов найти максимальный.

А то сейчас у вас вместо логики спагетти.

---
Браться за "оптимизацию" нужно лишь тогда, когда алгоритм понятен и работает. Так что не пытайтесь сделать всё зараз до тех пор, пока не получите работающий вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто вынести метод вывода на экран из цикла и не переприсваивать максмин на каждой итерации:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a[][] = {
    { 23, 6, 3 },
    { 2, 3, 4 },
    { 1, 8, 2 } };
  int min = 0;
  int maxmin = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // чтобы любое другое значение было больше
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        if (a[i][j] < a[i][min]) {
            min = j;
        }
    }
    // тут больше нет присваивания на каждом цикле
    if (maxmin < a[i][min]) {
        maxmin = a[i][min];
    }
  }
  System.out.println(maxmin); // вывод максмина вне цикла
}
```